# When using Group Policy to join a wireless network, can I specify the WPA2 passphrase?

Tags: windows, wifi

I'm using Group Policy to add my laptops to the wireless network, I appreciate they will initially need to be wired for the policy to apply. The problem I have is the whilst the SSID and encryption options are being correctly set by GPO I still have to click Connect on each laptop and enter the pass phrase. Can the pass phrase be set by Group Policy? I can't see anyway to do this.

We are using Windows 7 clients.

Comment: Can you use RADIUS with the wirelss AP?

Comment: Which version(s) of Windows are the clients running?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a static (preshared) key for a wireless connection via group policy. The 802.11 wireless policies in GP require that you use another authentication mechanism (e.g. RADIUS) if you want your wireless connections to be authenticated without user intervention.
Part of the reason for this is that group policy settings are stored in unencrypted files accessible to most everyone in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround (I love workarounds) is to have Group Policy reference a wireless profile [see](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301(v=ws.10).aspx) stored on a secured network location. Probably not the best way to get around it, but it'll work.